# Plugins not working in controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm building my first Zend Framework 2 application with the skeleton tutorial. But whenever I try to call any plugin from any controller, I get the error message:

> A plugin by the name "***PLUGIN_NAME***" was not found in the plugin manager
>   Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager

Unfortunately I don't know which part of the code could help you to help me. I post some files which I think could be important.

**config/modules.config**

```
return [
    'Zend\Router',
    'Zend\Validator',
    'Zend\Form',
    'Album',
    'Application',
    'User',
];
```

**module/User/src/Module.php**

```
<?php

namespace User;

use User\Model\User;
use User\Model\UserTable;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class Module
{
    const VERSION = '1.0.0dev';

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'User\Model\UserTable' =>  function($sm) {
                    $tableGateway = $sm->get('UserTableGateway');
                    $table = new UserTable($tableGateway);
                    return $table;
                },
                'UserTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new User());
                    return new TableGateway('user', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

**module/User/config/module.config.php**

```
<?php

namespace User;

use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;

return [
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\UserController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
        'invokables' => [
            'User\Controller\User' => 'User\Controller\UserController',
        ],
    ],

    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'user' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/user[/:action[/:id]]',
                    'constraints' => [
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ],
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\UserController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],

    'view_manager' => [
        'template_path_stack' => [
            'user' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
];
```

I'm trying to call my plugins like this from a controller action:

```
$this->flashMessanger()->...
$this->identity();
$this->getServiceLocator();
```

Because I really needed the Service Locator, I found a workaround, which is not so nice I think, but works for me:

```
$sm = $this->getEvent()->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
```

But I guess something is wrong here.

**Edit:**

For a better reproduction of what I did (I installed Zend Framework again and it still gives me the same error):

1. Installed Zend Framework (2.4 I guess?) by this installation guide (https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/ref/installation.html). I installed it with the following command:

   composer create-project -sdev --repository-url="https://packages.zendframework.com" zendframework/skeleton-application
2. On the installation, when I was asked if I want to install a minimum install, I chose "No". Every next question I answered with "Yes" (the installer asks to install a lot of modules, I installed them all).
3. The installer asked in which config I want to inject "ZendDeveloperTools". I answered 2 (config/development.config.php.dist). For all others I chose 1 (config/modules.config.php).
4. I tested the skeleton application by calling the url in my browser, it worked.
5. I downloaded the Album module from GitHub here (https://github.com/Hounddog/Album).
6. I copied the album module to my modules folder.
7. I added the entry 'Album' to my config/modules.config.php file
8. I browsed to the album page
9. I'm getting the error:

> A plugin by the name "getServiceLocator" was not found in the plugin
>   manager Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager

I assume the reason for this error is the getAlbumTable() method in the AlbumController

```
public function getAlbumTable()
{
    if (!$this->albumTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->albumTable = $sm->get('Album\Model\AlbumTable');
    }
    return $this->albumTable;
}
```

Comment: Which version of Zend Framework 2 are you using ?

Comment: @newage I followed the instructions of the documentations for Zend Framework version 2.4. I don't know how to find out the exact installed version, because when I try to call `echo \Zend\Version\Version::VERSION;'` I get an error (`Class 'Zend\Version\Version' not found`). Via `composer show --installed` I get a detailled list of all modules installed and a warning, that this action is deprecated.

Comment: You can use command `composer show zendframework/zendframework` for get a version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [the ZF2 docs for controller plugins](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html) you can read that your controller has to implement the following methods: `setPluginManager`, `getPluginManager` and `plugin`. You can also read:

> For an extra layer of convenience, both `AbstractActionController` and `AbstractActionController` have `__call()` implementations that allow you to retrieve plugins via method calls:
>
> `$plugin = $this->url();`

Does your controller extend `AbstractActionController` or `AbstractActionController`? 
If yes, it should work as mentioned in the docs (so those methods you mention in your question should work).
Since you didn't share any controller code it is hard to say whether this is the problem...

---

### UPDATE

The error you get is not related to the configuration of your `ControllerPluginManager`, but you get this error because you are doing:

```
$sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
```

Since the method `getServiceLocator` doesn't exist the magic `__call()` method is executed and this leads to the error.

This is because in the latest versions of ZF2 the controller classes are no longer *'service locator aware'* meaning you cannot retrieve the `ServiceManager` by calling `$this->getServiceLocator()`.

Instead you will have to inject your `Album\Model\AlbumTable` service into the controller class inside a factory:

**1)** Add a constructor method to your controller class:

```
public function __construct(AlbumTable $albumTable){
    $this->albumTable = $albumTable;
}
```

**2)** Create a factory for your controller:

```
<?php
namespace Album\Controller\Factory;

use Album\Controller\AlbumController;

class AlbumControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param  ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return AlbumController
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $controllerPluginManager = $serviceLocator;
        $serviceManager = $controllerPluginManager->get('ServiceManager');
        $albumTable = $serviceManager->get('Album\Model\AlbumTable');
        return new  AlbumController($albumTable);
    }
}
```

**3)** Register your controller factory inside your `module.config.php`:

```
'factories' => [
    `Album\Controller\AlbumController` => `Album\Controller\Factory\AlbumControllerFactory`,
],
```

Comment: My controller extends `AbstractActionController`. I edited my post with more information about reproducing the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The function `getAlbumTable()` was used in ZF2 tutorial but in ZF3 it was replaced by member `table`.

Change the `deleteAction()` function in `AlbumController.php` to read:

```php
public function deleteAction()
{
    $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
    if (!$id) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album');
    }

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $del = $request->getPost('del', 'No');

        if ($del == 'Yes') {
            $id = (int) $request->getPost('id');
            $this->table->deleteAlbum($id);
        }

        // Redirect to list of albums
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album');
    }

    return array(
        'id'    => $id,
        'album' => $this->table->getAlbum($id)
    );
}
```

Note the two lines reading `$this->table->...` instead of `$this->getAlbumTable()->...`